# cannot open ips file - iOS crash report - seems to be json format, rather then the previous crash format

Tags: ios, crash, crash-reports

the crash report seems to have changed format, now it is json.

the file ends in .ips.beta, renaming it to .crash does not help.
cannot be dragged to devices logs. the CLI symbolicatecrash does not work either.

how can i symbolicate it?